# ¿Cómo cambiar el scroll actual a uno regular?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un sitio que retomé desde otro sitio que ya tenía la empresa, en la página de "Localizar sucursal", al presentar los datos de la sucursal, a manera de lista; el scroll es infinito y no es responsive, ya que al verlo en un celular, es complicado bajar el scroll. Lo que me interesa es que en lugar de flechas verdes, sea únicamente la barra regular del navegador y no sea infinito.

La verdad que no sé mucho de programación, lo que sé es bastante básico.

La página es la [siguiente](http://www.laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx/website/localizatusucursal.php).

Ya hice las correccciones del div incompleto y los estilos que faltaban, pero aun no puedo con el `scroll`.

**PHP "localizatusucursal.php"**

```
<code>


</script>
<div class="page">

  <div class="consult_suc_selects" style="padding-bottom: 2%">
  Estado 
  <select id="estado" name="estado" class="rc4">
   <option>Seleccione un estado</option>   
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Ciudad
   <select id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="rc4">
    <option>-----------&nbsp;&nbsp; </option>
   </select>

 </div>

 <div> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCh1gZvUsD9ljetIt-i5jfTPtXhHB8uq7Y&sensor=true"> </script>

   <div>

        <div id="sucursales" class="sucursales col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding: 2%">
        <br /><br />
        Seleccione un estado y una ciudad.
    <!--        <ul >

     <li>          
        <span><b>1. Av. México </b></span><br />
         Prolongación Av. México, Plaza las Lomas Local No. 8<br />
         Col. Plaza Villarhermosa, C.P.76179 Villahermosa Tabasco<br />
         01 (993) 1-39-35-54                      <b><a href="#">Ver Mapa</a></b>
         <br /></li>
        <li>          
        <span>1. Av. México </span><br />
         Prolongación Av. México, Plaza las Lomas Local No. 8<br />
         Col. Plaza Villarhermosa, C.P.76179 Villahermosa Tabasco<br />
         01 (993) 1-39-35-54                      <b>Ver Mapa</b>
        <br /></li>
     <li>          
        <span>1. Av. México </span><br />
         Prolongación Av. México, Plaza las Lomas Local No. 8<br />
         Col. Plaza Villarhermosa, C.P.76179 Villahermosa Tabasco<br />
         01 (993) 1-39-35-54                      <b><a href="#">Ver Mapa</a></b>
        <br /></li>




      </ul>
        -->  

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/simplyscroll/re_.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/simplyscroll/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/simplyscroll/jquery.simplyscroll.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/simplyscroll/jquery.simplyscroll.css" media="all" type="text/css">


-->


      </div>

<!--         <div class="box_consult_suc_izq_flechas">
        ss
        <br />-<br /> 
        ss 
      </div>-->

      </div>

<!--       <div class="box_consult_suc_mid"></div>
-->
   <div class="mapa col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="showMap">
       <!-- <img src="images/local_suc_map.png"  /> -->
      </div>


 </div><br />


</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {    



  $(".d1_der_box_mid").addClass("box_consult_suc_selected");    


 $(".box_consult_suc").hide().animate({
    width: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
    height: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
      opacity: "toggle"
 }, 1500, "linear", function() {
    //$( this ).after( "<div>Animation complete.</div>" );
 });


});
</script> 

<!--------------------fin--------------->

  </div></div>
  </code>
```

**El scroll está en otro archivo llamado p_citys.php, donde encontré estas opciones del scroll**

```
<code>
  echo $res."</ul>             
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     (function($) {
     $(function() {
      $('#sucs').simplyScroll({
      customClass: 'vert',
      orientation: 'vertical',
      auto: false,
      manualMode: 'loop',
        frameRate: 40,
        speed: 10           
    });
    });
     })(jQuery);

    </script>"; 
</code>
```

Comment: Hola Rebeca, te sugiero que leas  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por otro lado, como recomendación personal, es que te tomes un tiempo para emprolijar tu código. Eso ayuda mucho a la hora de buscar un error o de editar algo mas adelante.

Comment: Gracias, hice unas ediciones, espero ser más comprensible

Comment: La lista no es infinita. El problema que tiene, es que re repite 3 veces.

Comment: Hola @RebecaLopezCobarrubias si la respuesta la hallaste por ti misma, en bien de la comunidad debes autoresponder tu pregunta y darla como respuesta correcta o elegir de las respuestas dadas, cual fue la más cercana. Éxitos!

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esconder los botones verdes puedes agregar en el `css`un `display:none`

```
.simply-scroll-back simply-scroll-btn simply-scroll-btn-up,simply-scroll-forward simply-scroll-btn simply-scroll-btn-down{
  display:none
}
```

Esto esconde los 2 botones.

Por otro lado, para poder scrolear la lista tienes que editar el `css` de la clase que contiene el `ul`. Ponerle una altura por defecto

```
.simply-scroll-list{
  height: 300;
}
```

Y a el `ul` de adentro ponerle la misma altura

```
#sucs{
  overflow: overlay;
  height: 300px
}
```

Por ultimo, tu lista parece infinita, pero no lo es. Tiene generadas, 3 listas iguales, en un mismo div. Por lo que cuando terminas una, automaticamente te aparece la otra. Busca eliminar de alguna manera las 2 listas extras que se generan.

Comment: Le quité `manualMode: 'loop',` y con eso solucioné la lista infinita. Gracias, lo de los estilos también me sirvió!